# Karate automatically sets Content-Type header

Tags: web-services, testing, automated-tests, bdd, karate

Good day! In my negative test cases I have to PUT a request without Content-Type header in order to match desired 4xx status code. The problem is karate automatically sets an appropriate Content-Type.
E.g. when I pass {} as request it sets application/json; charset=UTF-8
when I pass '' as request it sets text/plain; charset=UTF-8

The question is how can I send a PUT request without a Content-Type header?

Answer (score 4):

You can pass Content-Type by using the below line:

**And header Content-Type = 'application/json; charset=utf-8'**

Answer (score 3):

Just set `* configure charset = null`:

Here is the documentation: https://github.com/intuit/karate#configure

For a detailed example, see: [`content-type.feature`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/headers/content-type.feature)

Comment: Sorry, but the question is how can I send a PUT/POST request without a Content-Type header, not without charset.

Comment: @firstNamelastName - sorry this is not supported, the best you can do is set the `Content-Type` to an empty string. you are the first EVER to have asked for this - so if this is very important for you - please contribute a patch, this is an open-source project after all - else write this particular test in pure java.