# Karate API: Getting "405 Method Not Allowed" Error when sending request with PUT method

Tags: postman, karate

I am getting the error below when sending a request with PUT method.

```
1 < 405
1 < Allow: GET,HEAD,POST,OPTIONS
1 < Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
1 < Date: Mon, 17 Aug 2020 04:01:07 GMT
1 < Server: Apache
1 < Vary: Accept-Encoding
1 < Via: 1.1 
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>405 Method Not Allowed</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Method Not Allowed</h1>
<p>The requested method PUT is not allowed for the URL /xyz/abc/def/-1.</p>
</body></html>

[Fatal Error] :1:50: White spaces are required between publicId and systemId.
13:01:07.437 [main] WARN  com.intuit.karate - xml parsing failed, response data type set to string: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 50; White spaces are required between publicId and systemId.
```

My Request Body looks like:

```
{
  "i": {
    "x1": {
      "q": 10
    },
    "x2": {
      "q": 50
    }
  }
}
```

Can anyone guide me to resolve the issue?

NOTE:

1. The API Supports PUT method and the request we are trying to work with is the PUT one.
2. ***The same request works fine with Postman***.

My Code that makes the request

```html
 Scenario: Common Action
       * string testdata = read(sourceFilename)
       * def arr = LIB.getJsonArrayForElement(testdata, 'testCases')
       * eval logTC(arr[cnt].caseId)       
       #setting c
       * def c = arr[cnt].request.c == null ? 'Y' : arr[cnt].request.c
       #setting b
       * def b = arr[cnt].request.b == null ? 'Z' : arr[cnt].request.b
       #setting s
       * def s = arr[cnt].request.s == null ? '' : arr[cnt].request.s
       #setting i
       * def i = arr[cnt].request.i == null ? '' : arr[cnt].request.i
       #setting d
       * def d = arr[cnt].request.d == null ? false : arr[cnt].request.d
       #setting v
       * def v = arr[cnt].request.v == null ? '' : arr[cnt].request.v
       #setting f
       * def f = arr[cnt].request.f == null ? false : arr[cnt].request.f
       #setting es
       * def es = arr[cnt].expected.s == null ? 999999 : arr[cnt].expected.s
       * eval if(es == 999999 && typeof ess != 'undefined') karate.set('es', ess)
       * eval if(es == 999999) karate.set('es', 200)
       #preparing endpoint              
       * def endpoint = utils.getUrl(c, b, s, i, v, d)              
       
   Given url endpoint
     And request arr[cnt].request.body
    When method PUT 
    Then assert responses == es
       # for the cases where we are expecting 404
       * if (es == 404) karate.abort() 
       # for cases != 404
       * def expRes = '<empty>' 
       * eval if(es != 204) karate.set('expRes', arr[cnt].expected.body)
       * def actRes = '<empty>'
       * eval if(es != 204) karate.set('actRes', response)
     And match actRes == expRes
```

cURL

```html
curl --location --request PUT 'http://host-url/c/Y/b/X/s/2/i/1/v/-1' \
--header 'X-Client-Id: test' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
  "i": {
    "x1": {
      "q": 10
    },
    "x2": {
      "q": 50
    }
  }
}'
```

Comment: Well, the response is clear that PUT is not allowed. Don't you want to POST? Not all APIs support every HTTP verb.

Comment: @ranisalt the API supports PUT and we need to make the request with PUT method.

Comment: It does not support for the URL you are using. See the line that starts with `Allow`, it does not contain `PUT`, which means `PUT` is not supported for that specific URL. Perhaps the URL is missing a fragment?

Comment: @ranisalt I have added a note about it. Postman works fine with the same request.

Comment: @ShafiqulKabir then use Postman :) ok but seriously, provide a cURL command that works as part of your question. else please assume that Karate does not support what you want

Comment: @PeterThomas I have added my code in the description. Can you have a look if I am making any mistake there or missing anything?

Comment: @ShafiqulKabir sorry I can't read your code. here we need to know what the server expects. if you can't provide a cURL command you can wait for someone else to help you. all the best. normally I request this process to be followed: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: @PeterThomas Added my cURL command. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This request works absolutely fine for me, so most likely your server was expecting something else, or maybe it is an actual bug in your server. Please work with the team who owns the server, you should be able to find the issue in no time.

```
* url 'http://httpbin.org'
* header X-Client-Id = 'test'
* path 'put'
* request
"""
{
  "i": {
    "x1": {
      "q": 10
    },
    "x2": {
      "q": 50
    }
  }
}
"""
* method put
```

Other troubleshooting tips:

- Postman adds some headers automatically such as `Accept` watch out for that and add that if needed
- Karate appends `; charset=UTF-8` to the `Content-Type` header by default, which in rare cases the server does not like (most likely a bug on your server-side) - you can disable this by `* configure charset = null` - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/53651454/143475

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response and help Peter. We already figured out that there is an issue with our proxy server.