# Uploading an image using Multipart by karate API tool

Tags: cucumber, karate

I am trying to upload an image on our channel using Karate. It's getting response status as 200 but image is not uploaded on site. I tried it with postman and it worked but I am failing while doing it with karate. I don't what wrong I am doing.

```
Background: 
 * url "Url"
 * def queryString ={"mode":"singleUpload","isUploadedFromInstance":"true","klassId":"image_asset","requestId":"1dde25a1-64e9-4d63-a16b-48e94c208db9","lang":"en_US", "organizationId":"-1","physicalCatalogId":"pim","portalId":"pim","endpointId":"null","endpointType":"null","dataLanguage":"en_US"}

  Scenario: Create Task
    Given path 'assets/upload'
    And params queryString
    And multipart file code = { read: 'cla.jpg' , filename: 'cla.jpg', contentType: 'image/jpeg' }
    And multipart field message = 'image test'
    When method POST
    Then status 200
    * print response
    * print responseStatus
```

Comment: the only way to solve this is provide a way to replicate: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: and also see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63444862/143475